# Можно ли в ILIKE ANY() передать пустое поле и вывести записи

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть запрос фильтров.

```
SELECT P.* FROM PRODUCTS AS P WHERE P.CATEGORIES ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['${categories}'])
```

В переменной `categories` лежать названия или название категории, Все работает хорошо.

Вопрос, если переменная `categories` пустая, то есть нет ни одной категории, как вывести все записи вне зависимости от категории?

Comment: Добавить `OR 'в categories ни хрена нету'`.

Comment: @Akina `ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['${categories}']) OR ''` Правильно?

Comment: Нет. Вы должны проверить `'${categories}'` на пустоту, а не добавлять абстрактную пустую строку.

Comment: @Akina Проверить в запросе? Вот такой запрос ничего не возвращает `SELECT P.* FROM PRODUCTS AS P WHERE P.CATEGORIES ILIKE ANY(ARRAY[''])`